# How to concatenate with single row datafile

Tags: numpy, concatenation

I have 3 files A, B and C consist different shape data. How to concatenate using NumPy for the data. I have problem with File B as it contains only single row.

Previously, I didn't have problem when the data is more than two rows.

This is my Python program:

```
import numpy as np
import glob

files3=glob.glob(path2+'File*.dat')
arrays3 = [np.loadtxt(name3) for name3 in files3]
    
combined3 = np.concatenate(arrays3)
       
np.savetxt(path2+'30-Data.dat',combined3,fmt='%9.3f')
```

The program shows this error:

> all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the
> array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1
> dimension(s)

```
FileA.dat
    0.308   112.055     2.000     3.733     
    0.212   112.647     2.000     1.282     
    0.135   112.907     2.000     6.627     
    0.194   112.785     2.000     3.311 

FileB.dat
    0.261   112.116     2.000     1.575
 
FileC.dat
    0.308   112.055     2.000     3.733     
    0.212   112.647     2.000     1.282     
    0.135   112.907     2.000     6.627
```

Expected output is:

```
0.308   112.055     2.000     3.733     
0.212   112.647     2.000     1.282     
0.135   112.907     2.000     6.627     
0.194   112.785     2.000     3.311     
0.261   112.116     2.000     1.575     
0.308   112.055     2.000     3.733     
0.212   112.647     2.000     1.282     
0.135   112.907     2.000     6.627
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

when numpy reads a file with only one row it generates 1d array with shape `(ncols)`, (where `ncols` - number of columns in your textfile), but the rest of arrays are 2d with shape `(nrows,ncols)`,

you can force arrays to have 2 dimensions by doing this:

```py
arrays3 = [np.loadtxt(name3,ndmin=2) for name3 in files3]
```

Comment: @YevKad...Yes!!...got the answers. million thanks. I shall proceed with the bulky data in folders. hope it performs very well